# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, vb.net, iis, connection-string

I have inherited a website from a friend to host as he fell out with the current person hosting it for him.

Its an old site, was hosted is IIS7 by looks of things and i cant get it online.

Im on a server 2012r2 box with IIS

Basically this is the error i get:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Source Error:

Line 95: 
Line 96:             conOleDbConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("SQLClient").ConnectionString)
Line 97:             conOleDbConnection.Open()
Line 98: 
Line 99:             dadOleDbDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conOleDbConnection)


Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\App_Code\SqlClient.vb    Line: 97

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand() +7116997
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection) +30
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +312
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +202
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +413
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +128
   BBS.SqlClient.DataHandler.GetDataTable(String strSQL) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\App_Code\SqlClient.vb:97
   BBS.SqlClient.DataHandler.GetDataRow(String strSQL) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\App_Code\SqlClient.vb:128
   BBS.Sql.AbstractEntity.LoadObjectByCol(String strColumnName, String strColumnValue) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\App_Code\AbstractEntity.vb:216
   _Default.Bind(String strWebPageURL) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\Default.aspx.vb:9
   _Default.Page_Load(Object s, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\Default.aspx.vb:30
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785
```

So here are the relevant sections of the stack trace files:

SQLCLIENT.VB line 97

```
Public Shared Function GetDataTable(ByVal strSQL As String) As DataTable
Dim conOleDbConnection As SqlConnection
Dim dadOleDbDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dstDataSet As New DataSet

conOleDbConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("SQLClient").ConnectionString)
conOleDbConnection.Open()

dadOleDbDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conOleDbConnection)
dadOleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dstDataSet, "Data")

conOleDbConnection.Close()
conOleDbConnection = Nothing

Return dstDataSet.Tables("Data")
End Function
```

SQLCLIENT.VB Line 128

```
Public Shared Function GetDataRow(ByVal strSQL As String) As DataRow
Dim dtblGetDataRow As DataTable = GetDataTable(strSQL)

If dtblGetDataRow.Rows.Count = 1 Then Return dtblGetDataRow.Rows(0) Else Return Nothing
End Function
```

Here is the connection string from the web.config been supplied

```
<connectionStrings>
<add connectionString="" name="SQLClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

have put the database onto an MSSQL server

try adding in a new connection string:

```
<add name="MSSQL" connectionString="Data Source=abc;Initial Catalog=def Name;User id=geh;Password=ijk;Persist Security Info=true;Pooling=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But then it erros with all kinds.

Can anybody help me get this website back online please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using Persist Security Info=true which means it is using a Windows Credentials so you do not need a username and password.  Start by verifying the database is working by using SQL Server Management which comes with SQL Server and see if you can login.  Then the instance of the server in the SSMS login window should be the same in your connection string.

Comment: Taking persist security info out just errors it on line 96 instead of 97.  I can login to the instance with the creds and see the db so that's setup fine, the website just isn't connecting too it. If i take out the mssql connection string and use the sqlclient string as supplied it still errors on line 96.

Comment: I said to take out User and Password.  SSMS is working and is using a Windows Credential.  So the connection string must also use Windows credential (Trusted_Connection=True).  So use : Server=myServerAddress(instance from SSMS login window);Initial Catalog=def Name; Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: Ah ok, I set the db connection string up with a sql auth user not windows. What windows user will it use? The site anonymous auth and app pool are both set to app pool identity.

Comment: The login account.  You should set up a window group account and make the database use the group account.  Then add users to the group account so you can have more than one user access the database and add users in Windows instead of the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added a new connection string, but with a different name. The name in your config file must match the name that your code is looking for ("SQLClient").

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="you need to put something here" name="SQLClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You can get rid of the `MSSQL`. Take the connectionString from that and put it in the SQLClient entry. Or rename from MSSQL to SQLClient and ditch the extra.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is empty and you renamed the connection from SQLClient to MSSQL.

Use SSMS to check that <DOMAIN>\<WEBSERVERNAME>$ (your new IIS computer name) has login permission and the User Mapping for the DB. Also test the connection from your DEV PC to MSSQL. In VS,use the Server Explorer to connect to the MSSQL PC and DB. Get the properties of that Data Connection. The connection string can look like...

```
Data Source=<sqlservername>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Integrated Security=True
```

...where <sqlservername> and <database> is the name of the PC and database without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("SQLClient").ConnectionString actually returns something. By looking at your code, SQLClient doesn't have much in it. It should look something like this.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SQLClient" connectionString="Data Source=abc;Initial Catalog=def Name;User id=geh;Password=ijk;Persist Security Info=true;Pooling=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I think if the connection string was actually wrong, you'll get a different error.

Comment: the_lotus - thankyou. the previous guy had obviously stripped out his details by removing the whole line, rather than just the details. Using    <add name="SQLClient" connectionString="Data Source=abc;Initial Catalog=def;User id=ghi;Password=jki;Pooling=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> brings the site up. THANKYOU

Answer (score 0):

the previous guy had obviously stripped out his details by removing the whole line, rather than just the details. Using  brings the site up.

Thanks to the_lotus and Mason for pointing me in the right direction.